# Which is the better option for my dependents, L2 or B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, air-travel, customs-and-immigration

I currently have a B2 visa. I intend to bring my wife and son for visit to the US for travel and pleasure with me, and so I would like them to apply for their own B2 visa. My current company intends to apply for an L1B visa for me, for an upcoming work assignment. Which is the better option for my dependents? Option 1) Apply for a B2 visa? or Option 2) Apply for an L2 (I believe that is the dependent visa for L1B holders) once I get the L1B visa? The intention is also to be able to travel in the future for pleasure and visit.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: Good evening Sir @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, by that I meant, easier to get approval and more flexible for future travel to the US for pleasure and visit.

Comment: Based on my personal experience I would do the L2 for them. That's because if your L1B is approved it is virtually automatic that their L2 would be approved (while that is not the case with B2). After your work assignment, next time they want to visit USA and apply B2 their chances of getting approved are very high because they demonstrated compliance with the L2 (which is technically a higher visa than B2) and returned to your home country.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Thank you sir for the valuable info. I have a follow-up inquiry. I went to the US for legit business purpose via B1 for 3 months (from January this year and went back home to my country on March). I heard that some people who went home from the US on same case (stayed in US on B1 for 3 months) got rejected and their B1 /B2 visa multiple entry visa was cancelled by the consular officer during the L1B visa interview. Is this really a possibility?

Comment: `Is this really a possibility?` Yes [it is a possibility](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/holding-two-us-visas-at-the-same-time--565856.html) and happens sometimes. However one is allowed to have different kinds of non-immigrant US visas simultaneously, e.g. F1 and B1/B2 although you can only use one at any particular time. Some of the consular officers don't know this and automatically cancel your other visa when issuing a new one. Make sure to explain at your interview that you plan to use the other visa at another time.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Is it advisable sir that I now apply for L1B given that my last trip to the US on B1 was just a few months back?

Comment: Why not? The L1 is for work, the B1/B2 was for visit. They are different things and there is no limit to the number of times you can enter the USA in a year and particularly in your case the reason for the trips are different. You are worrying too much. However the question I have for you is how come you spent 3 months in the USA? Someone who is working cannot be taking 3 months off for vacation in USA just like that. Be ready for such questions from the consular. If they suspect you were working in the USA while on B1 contrary to the law, you're totally finished.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on your intentions and how long you'll be in the US.

A [B-2 visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) is for temporary visits, usually for up to six months at a time or less. Your wife and son would need to demonstrate that their permanent home remained outside the US, and they could be questioned on entry about their intent to go back home. They would not be allowed to work or study in the US or remain in the country indefinitely.

An [L-2 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-2_visa) would allow your wife and son to stay in the US for as long as you can, and grants other benefits. Your wife could get an Employment Authorization Document and work in the United States and your son could attend school. Under various circumstances, it's possible, maybe, that you could eventually adjust status to become US permanent residents and remain in the US if you wish (whether or not that's something you're interested in now, it's possible you could change your mind in the future).

Since your company is sponsoring you for an L-1 visa, it would be best to talk to the immigration lawyers handling the matter to get professional advice, as your choice now has ramifications for future possibilities in the US.

Comment: Good evening @Zach Lipton, thank you so much for the very valuable advise. May I ask for further clarifications please? About the statement "Under various circumstances, you could eventually adjust status to become US permanent residents and remain in the US if you wish", I was under the impression that L1B has no dual intent, hence it would be difficult to adjust status to become US permanent residents. Please explain further and feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @juniebonifacio My understanding is that all types of L-1 visas are [dual intent](http://www.katzlawchicago.com/blogs/699-going-from-l1-visa-to-green-card-heres-how-to-do-it). What I'm honestly not sure of is how feasible it actually is to adjust status to gain permanent residency with an L1B. It's much easier as a manager/executive, more difficult for "specialized skills or knowledge" where a labor certification is needed. Whether your employer would petition for you to stay in the US and what kind of chances you would have would be a great question for the lawyers arranging your L-1 visa.

Comment: @juniebonifacio You might want to ask about the specifics of obtaining permanent residency under an L-1B visa over at our [expatriates site](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/), as we're getting away from travel-related knowledge and people over there may know more about this specific detail.